# CakePHP returning HTML from remote site page to view through AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to add a form request to my page that will return some HTML to the user through an AJAX call. I am using CakePHP framework and the built in helpers to do an AJAX request. I've tried multiple ways of performing the request and returning the HTML that comes back to a response DIV. But it appears there are some heavy issues that prevent you from calling an external page and returning it.

I know my GET query is working correctly because I can copy the firebug request location into a browser and get the proper formatted response page.

From the searching I've done I've gathered that you aren't allowed to do cross browser requests and you have to do some sort of redirect from your controller. I've tried several things without success there as well. If I simply change my ajax request to a local controller action it does work. But I need to display the request response from my external page that returns data from another server. I have control of both servers and pages.

What is the proper way to set this up in CakePHP?

Comment: Do you have auth permit on that remote page? better show some code

Comment: Just get it working in Javascript, and post that code if you need help converting, or post the Javascript question itself - this kind of hybrid without any code makes it tough to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite understand exactly what you've tried, but yes, in simple terms you can't use AJAX to request content from a different domain. What you can do is use PHP as a proxy, which I think is what you're suggesting.

So, if you have a Things controller with a 'stuff' action, your AJAX requests content from your CakePHP site like this:

```
$.getJSON('/things/stuff', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

You 'stuff' action would then use PHP to get the external content (using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), for example) and return it ('data' above) to your AJAX callback.

```
function stuff() {
    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.stuff.com/thing');
    $this->set('content', $content);
}
```

That should do what you want.

Toby

Comment: Toby, This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I am getting a warning however from file_get_contents. [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! I do see some of the file being returned though. It doesn't appear that the HTML is being parsed either. But I think this is exactly what I need if I can work out this kink. Is it possible maybe I should use $this->render instead of $this->set

Comment: You can output the contents however you want, obviously you may want to alter it, json_encode it or whatever. If your URL is parameterized you could try using urlencode() to make sure it doesn't get mangled, does that help? Presumably the URL works in a browser?